# Image distorted when converting svg stream to png using ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, base64, imagemagick

I get distorted image when converting svg to png and showing it on rails view.

This is how I am converting:

```
img = Magick::Image.from_blob(text_svg) {
          self.format = 'SVG'
      }
img = img.first.to_blob {
         self.format = 'PNG'
      }

@img = Base64.encode64(img)
```

I am rendering Base64 on view by:

```
<%=image_tag "data://image/png;base64," + @img %>
```

Base64:

```
PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciICB3aWR0 
aD0iMTIwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEyMCIgdmlld1BvcnQ9IjAgMCAxMjAgMTIwIiB2 ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiPjxnIGlkPSJQTDAxX1RFWFRfR1JPVVAiPgogICAgPHBh dGggZD0iTTMzLjMzMjk5MywxNDUuMDA2MDI3IGM0NS42NywtNjEuODA2IDg1 LDEuODA2IDgwLDEuODA2IFoiIGlkPSJQTDAxX1RFWFRfUEFUSF9WRVJUSUNB TF9BUkNIIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIj48L3BhdGg+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNMjYu MzMyOTkzLDE0MC4wMDYwMjcgYzQwLjY3LDYxLjgwNiAxMDAsMi44MDYgOTUs Mi44MDYgWiIgaWQ9IlBMMDFfVEVYVF9QQVRIX1JFVkVSVF9BUkNIIiBmaWxs PSJub25lIj48L3BhdGg+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBkPSJNMjUuMzMzLDE0MC4wMDYw MjcgYzc0LjY3LDAgMTI4LDIuODA2IDExOSwyLjgwNiIgaWQ9IlBMMDFfVEVY VF9QQVRIX1NUUkFJR0hUIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIj48L3BhdGg+CiAgICA8dGV4 dCB5PSIwcHgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0iIiB4PSIwcHgiPgogICAgICAgIDx0ZXh0 UGF0aCB0ZXh0TGVuZ3RoPSIxMDAiIGlkPSJQTDAxX1RFWFRfUEFUSCIgeG1s bnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHhsaW5r OmhyZWY9IiNQTDAxX1RFWFRfUEFUSF9TVFJBSUdIVCI+CiAgICAgICAgICAg IDx0c3BhbiBzdHJva2U9Im5vbmUiIGlkPSJQTDAxX1RFWFQiIHN0cm9rZS13 aWR0aD0iMXB4IiBmb250LWZhbWlseT0iQXJpYWwiIGZpbGw9ImJsYWNrIiBm b250LXNpemU9IjMwcHgiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOiByZ2IoMCwgMCwgMCk7IGZv bnQtZmFtaWx5OiAmcXVvdDtBY2FkZW1pYyBNNTQmcXVvdDs7Ij5OYW1lPC90 c3Bhbj4KICAgICAgICA8L3RleHRQYXRoPgogICAgPC90ZXh0PgogICAgPHRl eHQgeT0iMTU1LjQ3MDk5M3B4IiBpZD0iUEwwMV9OVU1CRVJTIiB0ZXh0LWFu Y2hvcj0ibWlkZGxlIiB4PSI3Mi4zMzIwMDFweCIgd2lkdGg9IjkyLjgwMSIg aGVpZ2h0PSI3OS4zNzEiPgogICAgICAgIDx0c3BhbiBzdHJva2U9Im5vbmUi IGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJBcmlhbCIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIxcHgiIGlkPSJQ TDAxX05VTUJFUlNfVEVYVCIgdGV4dExlbmd0aD0iNzgiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDFi NDMiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iNjAiIGxlbmd0aEFkanVzdD0ic3BhY2luZ0FuZEds eXBocyI+PC90c3Bhbj4KICAgIDwvdGV4dD4KPC9nPjwvc3ZnPg==
```

how I am passing svg:

```
'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="120" height="120" viewPort="0 0 120 120" version="1.1">' + placement['decorations'][decoration_id]['text_svg'] + '</svg>'
```

SVG format is rendering fine but PNG is distorted. Any idea why?

Comment: The image tag is displaying base64 of the SVG text. Is that right?

Comment: no, image PNG blob created by imagemagick